# How to get UL / LI value in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need an array of Citys, how does it working in jquery? I never touch frontend so I'm very newbie.

```
<ul class="ui-autocomplete ui-front ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content" id="ui-id-180" tabindex="0" style="display: block; top: 166px; left: 1037.86px; width: 203px;">
<li class="ui-menu-item" id="ui-id-418" tabindex="-1">City1</li>
<li class="ui-menu-item" id="ui-id-419" tabindex="-1">City2</li>
<li class="ui-menu-item" id="ui-id-420" tabindex="-1">City3</li>
<li class="ui-menu-item" id="ui-id-421" tabindex="-1">City4</li></ul>
```

Also this list of citys is connected with input field. Values generated on server side. Main UL has id "ui-id-180" is it possible it may change on user side? Does input field connected with dropdown list? If so is it possible to know which "ul li" connected with which field?
My code to get value in input field:

```
$("[name=" + City.GetInputName() + "]").keyup(function(eventObject){
$("[name=" + Source.GetInputName() + "]").val(function(index, value){});});
```

**Update 1**
There is an [example](https://jsfiddle.net/9a2L5szc/) using @mplungjan answer.
If there is more than one UL the array has unwanted values. That's why I asked about connection of input field and UL ( to filtrate values).

Comment: Please post a [mcve]  - right now it is hard to guess what you are trying to do. Can you change the  server to add data-attributes for example

Comment: What is `City.GetInputName()` doing? Also I suggest delegation from the nearest container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how to get the cities in jQuery map without touching the ID

```js
const cities = $(".ui-autocomplete li")
  .map(function() { return this.textContent.trim()})
  .get();

console.log(cities)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="ui-autocomplete ui-front ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content" id="ui-id-180" tabindex="0" style="display: block; top: 166px; left: 1037.86px; width: 203px;">
  <li class="ui-menu-item" id="ui-id-418" tabindex="-1">City1</li>
  <li class="ui-menu-item" id="ui-id-419" tabindex="-1">City2</li>
  <li class="ui-menu-item" id="ui-id-420" tabindex="-1">City3</li>
  <li class="ui-menu-item" id="ui-id-421" tabindex="-1">City4</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: yeah, it works great but there is also few UL with class="ui-autocomplete ui-front ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content". And when they have the data - the array has unwanted values. I can't modify classes this is a part of crm system. Does jquery have a method to understand which ul connected with which input filed to filtrate values?

Comment: @Red_commie Possibly. I have no way of knowing since you have not provided the HTML that shows both in context

Comment: @Red_commie Sorry, I do not see any connection between fields in the fiddle. What is the expected access and functionality? what do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

if i understand the question correctly, you want to create an array containing the values of the `li` tags like this

```js
["City1", "City2", "City3", "City4"]
```

a way to do this by using the `map` method like this

```js
//use HTML DOM to target the <li> elements
let li = document.getElementsByClassName("ui-menu-item");
//display the values into the array
let array = [...li].map(e => e.innerHTML);

console.log(array); 
//output : ["City1", "City2", "City3", "City4"]
```

Comment: I would do `.textContent.trim()` and jQuery has a map also

Comment: @mplungjan can you help me add the jquery solution xD cuz i only use vanilla js

Comment: Here is the jQuery version: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68110412/295783 but I use vanilla more and more

Answer (score -1):

Code should be:

```
var cities = [];
  $('#cities').click(function(){ \\ Click event
    $.each($('li'), function(index,el){ \\Loop on cities
        cities.push($(el).text()); \\Pushing city name to an array
    });
    alert(cities);
    console.log(cities);
  })
```

```js
  var cities = [];
  $('#cities').click(function(){
    $.each($('li'), function(index,el){
        cities.push($(el).text());
    });
    alert(cities);
    console.log(cities);
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="ui-autocomplete ui-front ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content" id="ui-id-180" tabindex="0" style="display: block; top: 166px; left: 1037.86px; width: 203px;">
<li class="ui-menu-item" id="ui-id-418" tabindex="-1">City1</li>
<li class="ui-menu-item" id="ui-id-419" tabindex="-1">City2</li>
<li class="ui-menu-item" id="ui-id-420" tabindex="-1">City3</li>
<li class="ui-menu-item" id="ui-id-421" tabindex="-1">City4</li></ul>
<button id="cities">GET CITIES</button>
```

Hope this will be useful.

Comment: That is not an elegant way to get the cities and you will append the cities to the array every time you click - also OP did not ask for a button